# Config Server Firewall: You need to install the missing perl modules and then install cxs

Tags: debian, firewall, perl, csf

I am trying to install config server firewall however when i follow the tutorial and run install.sh i get the following error. Can anyone help?

```
root@localhost:~/csf# sh install.sh

Configuring for OS

Running csf generic installer

Installing generic csf and lfd

Check we're running as root

Checking Perl modules...
Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/csf /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 22) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 22) line 2.
Configuration modified for Debian/Ubuntu/Gentoo settings /etc/csf/csf.conf

You need to install the missing perl modules and then install cxs
root@localhost:~/csf#
```

Im running
Linux localhost 3.2.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 24 05:01:45 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Debian 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install  `libwww-perl`.

```
sudo aptitude install libwww-perl
```

OR

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::LWP'
```

OR

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.04.tar.gz
tar xzf libwww-perl-6.04.tar.gz
cd libwww-perl-6.04
perl Makefile.PL
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Done :) Yea i just had to wait 5 minutes before i could mark as accepted.